# XML сериализация List<IFigure>

Tags: c#, xml, serializable

**Доброго времени суток.** Необходимо сериализовать список фигур, реализующих общий интерфейс IFigure. Код сериализации:

```
        XmlSerializer f = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<IFigure>));
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("figures.xml", FileMode.Create);
        try {
            f.Serialize(fs, figures);
        }
        catch (SerializationException ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally {
            fs.Close();
        }
```

При попытке сериализовать список List возникли проблемы:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: Невозможно сериализовать интерфейс lab7_XML.IFigure.

Есть интерфейс:

```
public interface IFigure {
    double Area { get; }
    double this[int i] { get; }
    String coord();
    String Color { get; }
    String ADD { get; }
}
```

Его реализуют 2 класса, класс Circle:

```
[Serializable]
public class Circle : IFigure {
    public double[] coordXY;
    public string color;

    public Circle() { }

    public Circle(double[] coord, string color) {
        this.color = color;
        coordXY = new double[coord.Length];
        Array.Copy(coord, coordXY, coord.Length);
    }
}
```

И класс Rect:

```
[Serializable]
public class Rect : IFigure {
    public double[] coordXY;
    public string color;

    public Rect() { }

    public Rect(double[] coord, string color) {
        this.color = color;
        if (coord.Length > 8) throw new Exception("Слишком много вершин!");
        coordXY = new double[coord.Length];
        Array.Copy(coord, coordXY, coord.Length);
    }
}
```

С сериализацией списков обычных объектов у меня проблем не возникало. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться. Спасибо.

Comment: используйте вместо интерфейса абстрактный класс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте список объектов абстрактного типа, вместо интерфейса.

Пометьте атрибутом `[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedClass))]` все дочерние классы, которые хотите сериализовать:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Circle))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Rect))]
public abstract class Figure 
{
    //ваши свойства из интерфейса IFigure
}

[Serializable]
public class Circle : Figure
{    

}
[Serializable]
public class Rect : Figure
{

}
```

поменять:

```
XmlSerializer f = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<IFigure>));
```

на:

```
XmlSerializer f = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Figure>));
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: @IOr, всегда пожалуйста!